# TSQL query to use While loop iteratively to replace cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, cursor, database-cursor

I have the following code where I am trying to replace the cursor where i want to iteratively go though each fileid one by one and assign the output of that single fileid each time to the variable @fil, but its printing everything for all the iterations. Explored many forums, but couldn't find the solution. I know the solution in cursor but this is new to me!

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @count INT, @fil varchar(100) 
SELECT @count=  COUNT(DISTINCT m.FileID)
FROM [EDW].[FileMaster] m 

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
       
    @filid = SELECT DISTINCT m.FileID 
FROM [EDW].[FileMaster] m
    --OFFSET @i ROWS   
    --FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY  
    SET @i = @i + 1;
print @fileid
END
```

Expected output is `abc.txt def.txt ghi.txt etc`

Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHILE` is just as bad as a cursor ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but you're missing the whole point of SQL...

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0; 
DECLARE @count INT = COUNT(DISTINCT FileID) FROM [EDW].[FileMaster]);
DECLARE @fil varchar(100);

WHILE @i <= @count 
BEGIN 
SET @fil = SELECT DISTINCT FileID FROM [EDW].[FileMaster] 
ORDER BY FileID OFFSET @i ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
SET @i = @i + 1; 
print @fil 
END;
```

You can create a temp table with distinct FileIDs once and then cycle through it

Comment: thank you i appreciate it, thats fits perfectly . Also isnt temp table also needs OFFSET and fetch to a variable, whats the difference between my approach to of that, i can really adapt to that solution too, can you please add your solution beneath the above ones, i shall really appreciate it @jigga

Comment: The temp table solution is just for the performance... If your table is not too big and/or you have an index on FileID, you don't need a temp table. Else, SELECT DISTINCT FileID INTO #tmp FROM EDW.FileMaster. After that replace EDW.FileMaster with #tmp and drop the DISTINCT keyword